# Many commands are not found by zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

If I tab autocomplete, most of the time I get errors:

- If I do `vim [TAB]` to look for the files in the folder, it just jumps to the next command line.
- If I try to execute `rvm use 2.0.0 --default` I get `zsh: correct 'rvm' to 'rvim' [nyae]?`. If I say no, I get a *command not found* error.
- If I press `TAB` after typing `ruby -v`, zsh wants to correct to `_ruby -v`.
- If i type the complete command without `TAB`. zsh wants to correct `ruby` to `_ruby`
  and `rvm` to `rvim`

Is this any known bug or is there any help for this?

Edit: Added .zshrc

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="blinks"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment to change how often before auto-updates occur? (in days)
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable command autocorrection
# DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable marking untracked files under
# VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories much,
# much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git ruby rails autojump)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

autoload -U compinit && compinit

# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scriptingTH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: I addition to dayid's request, try to use `rehash` (rebuilds command hash table) and examine the output of `hash` if `rvm` and `ruby` is listed.

Comment: If you type a _complete_ `rvm` or `ruby` command and press `(Enter)`, does it work correctly?

Comment: As dayid's request is gone now -- for the records: Without your `~/.zshrc` file it's really hard to tell what's going on. Another point: Is `rvm` working with other shells? If so, what does `which rvm` in e.g. bash say?

Comment: @DennyMueller: Please (1a) review the edits that have been made to your question (click on the [edited _N_ hours ago](http://superuser.com/posts/612691/revisions) link), (1b) determine whether they are correct, (1c) if necessary, re-edit your question yourself (click on [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/612691/edit)) to make it right, and (2) answer my question ([above](http://superuser.com/questions/612691/many-commands-are-not-found-by-zsh/612805?noredirect=1#comment758959_612691)).

Comment: Made another edit, to clearify @Scott s answer.

Comment: First of all, you did not show whether `rvm` exists at all. Does it work if you execute it by specifying the full path? If it does, the error is in your PATH specification. Do a `echo $path`. Can you see the directory, where _rvm_ is in?

Comment: As a side note: In particular, if you mean by _rvm_ the Ruby Version Manager, this is not an executable, but a shell function, so fiddling with your PATH won't help. Note however, that this `rvm` was written with _bash_ in mind, so watch out for possible problems resulting from you using zsh.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

inside `.zprofile`, and
`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin`
inside `.zshrc`.

Edit: This is for rvm matter, I didn't met other errors. However, if I were you, I'd try  backing up existing zsh configuration files, then installing [grml-zsh-conf](http://grml.org/zsh/). (Of course you'll need to add rvm stuff on top of grml conf). If zsh now behaves normally, something is likely wrong in your conf. Please, show it, if you can.

Comment: This doesn’t address the OP’s problem, which focuses on autocomplete.  He does not say that he can’t run `rvm` at all.

Comment: Srsrly? "If I say no, I get a command not found error."

Comment: @Scott: IMHO the confusion arises due to doubleDown's edit of the question. I rejected it, but one vote was obviously not enough. I try to improve it to resemble the original meaning.

Comment: @mpy: Well, I’ll concede that the original draft of the question left something to be desired in the clarity department, but, in **my** humble opinion, [doubleDown](http://superuser.com/users/231614/doubledown)’s edit was better than yours.  So we’ll just have to wait for [Denny Mueller](http://superuser.com/users/165528/denny-mueller) to come back and clarify the matter by answering _our_ questions.

Comment: @Scott: My point is, that `zsh: correct 'rvm' to 'rvim' [nyae]?` is caused by _correction_ (which is triggered (by default) by `Ctrl-X-C` or `Enter` (option `correction` set) and not by _completion_ (which is triggered by `TAB`.

Comment: @mpy AFAIK, zsh triggers correction only when it can't find executable you entered. If executable exists in `PATH`, it's run as is. That's why I think it's `PATH` problem, not correction one.

Comment: @SzymonSzydełko: I agree absolutely.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, was offline quite a long time :/, as you see in my edit these entries are already in my .zshrc and also in my .zprofile.